# How to add time-sensitive data to governance proposals?

Tags: solidity, calldata, governance, mev

Many governance contracts use low level calls. In order to allow governance to call any contract, OpenZeppelin's governance bravo executes proposals through

```
targets[i].call{value: values[i]}(calldatas[i]);
```

where calldatas and values are both bytes[] and targets is address[].
However, this may take some time to pass the voting process. Is there any way to append more time-sensitive arguments to the call? What I am looking for is something like

```
targets[i].call{value: values[i]}(abi.encode(calldatas[i], timeSensitiveDatas[i]));
```

so that the original method signature and arguments remain untouched, but more time-sensitive arguments can be added later once the proposal is approved.

For example, let's say I want my governance contract to swap 1000 ETH to USDC (ignoring callback concerns, the data param, etc.).

```
function swap(
        address recipient,
        bool zeroForOne,
        int256 amountSpecified,
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96,
    )
```

I already know recipient, zeroForOne, and amountSpecified. I'd like to create a contract where I encode the calldata for swap(selector, recipient, zeroForOne, amountSpecified) and then concatenate the sqrtPriceLimitX96 when the proposal is executed to minimize slippage. However, I can't just add the sqrtPriceLimitX96 to the end as a uint160, because this same functionality may need to be used for other functions. The whole system must be able to take only byte arguments and work generally. When I try to do this, I run into issues, because `abi.encode(calldatas[i], timeSensitives[i])` will attempt to pass bytes on rather than a uint160, and `abi.encodePacked` will retain the byte data location encoding, which causes other issues.

So, I want to build a function that can construct any low level call, within a smart contract. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to use your own contract as target, and make the time sensitive computation there, then it will invoke the swap contract.

Comment: I like that! Unfortunately doesn't work with our architecture, but it's a great idea that I'll keep in mind for the future.

Comment: What I ended up building was something that compared the first X bytes of calldata to the first X bytes of proposed calldata (the latter including time sensitive data).